# reshape dataframe from multiple columns to one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
2014-11-26 09:05:19.669 -0.000610  0.000000 -0.001526 -0.000610 -0.000305   
2014-11-26 09:05:20.169 -0.000610 -0.000610  0.000305 -0.000610 -0.000610   
2014-11-26 09:05:20.669 -0.001831 -0.000916 -0.000610  0.000610 -0.000305   
2014-11-26 09:05:21.169 -0.000916 -0.000305 -0.000305 -0.000610 -0.000610   
2014-11-26 09:05:21.669  0.000000 -0.000916 -0.000610 -0.000305 -0.000610   
2014-11-26 09:05:22.171 -0.001221 -0.000610 -0.000305 -0.000610 -0.000610   
2014-11-26 09:05:22.669 -0.000916 -0.000305  0.000610 -0.000610 -0.000305   
2014-11-26 09:05:23.169 -0.000610 -0.000610 -0.001221 -0.001221 -0.000610
```

The index is datetime. The first columns is the data at that datetime. Subsequent data are taken intervals of 1 ms. So, column[0] is taken at index, column[1] at datetime+1ms, column[2] = datetime+2ms, ...
Is there a easy way to create a new dataframe with one column where all the datetimes has been calculated and inserted in the index in the correct position? There are 2500 of those columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact syntax can vary here depending on exactly how you begin.  I'm starting with the default index and the times are stored in a column 'index' and are of type datetime

```
>>> df

                    index         x         y         z
0 2014-11-26 09:05:19.669 -0.000610  0.000000 -0.001526
1 2014-11-26 09:05:20.169 -0.000610 -0.000610  0.000305
2 2014-11-26 09:05:20.669 -0.001831 -0.000916 -0.000610
3 2014-11-26 09:05:21.169 -0.000916 -0.000305 -0.000305
```

The first step is to stack the data so you have a single column, and then create a count-type column that will tell us how many milliseconds to add to each index.

```
>>> df2 = df.set_index('index').stack().reset_index()
>>> df2['cumcnt'] = df2.groupby('index',as_index=False).cumcount()

                     index level_1         0  cumcnt
0  2014-11-26 09:05:19.669       x -0.000610       0
1  2014-11-26 09:05:19.669       y  0.000000       1
2  2014-11-26 09:05:19.669       z -0.001526       2
3  2014-11-26 09:05:20.169       x -0.000610       0
4  2014-11-26 09:05:20.169       y -0.000610       1
5  2014-11-26 09:05:20.169       z  0.000305       2
6  2014-11-26 09:05:20.669       x -0.001831       0
7  2014-11-26 09:05:20.669       y -0.000916       1
8  2014-11-26 09:05:20.669       z -0.000610       2
9  2014-11-26 09:05:21.169       x -0.000916       0
10 2014-11-26 09:05:21.169       y -0.000305       1
11 2014-11-26 09:05:21.169       z -0.000305       2
```

Then multiply the 'cumcnt' column with a 1 millisecond TimeDelta and that's about it...

```
>>> df2['index'] = df2['index'] + pd.to_timedelta('1ms') * df2['cumcnt']

                     index level_1         0  cumcnt
0  2014-11-26 09:05:19.669       x -0.000610       0
1  2014-11-26 09:05:19.670       y  0.000000       1
2  2014-11-26 09:05:19.671       z -0.001526       2
3  2014-11-26 09:05:20.169       x -0.000610       0
4  2014-11-26 09:05:20.170       y -0.000610       1
5  2014-11-26 09:05:20.171       z  0.000305       2
6  2014-11-26 09:05:20.669       x -0.001831       0
7  2014-11-26 09:05:20.670       y -0.000916       1
8  2014-11-26 09:05:20.671       z -0.000610       2
9  2014-11-26 09:05:21.169       x -0.000916       0
10 2014-11-26 09:05:21.170       y -0.000305       1
11 2014-11-26 09:05:21.171       z -0.000305       2
```